# Pass block passed to method to another method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I'm trying to write a clone of the ruby `keep_if` and `delete_if` array methods. Here is my code.

```
module Strain
  def keep
    self.inject([]) do |extracts, element|
      yield(element) ? extracts << element : extracts 
    end
  end

  def discard
    self.inject([]) do |extracts, element|
      !yield(element) ? extracts << element : extracts
    end
  end
end

class Array
  include Strain
end
```

This works. But I want to do something like:

```
def discard
  self - self.keep &block
end
```

Desired behaviour:

```
[1, 2, 3].discard { |number| number < 2 }
# => [2, 3]
```

So I need to pass the block that is passed to the `discard` method, to be passed on to the `keep` method. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can reference the block explicitly

```
def discard(&block)
  self - self.keep(&block)
end
```

or implicitly

```
def discard
  self - self.keep(&Proc.new {})
end
```

In your case, I would suggest the first approach.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up solving it without passing the block, but I learned something nonetheless.

Comment: I'm surprised that's all this answer needed.  It sounded like a more complicated solution was desired.  I'll try to formulate and ask the original way I read the question

Answer (score 8):

In the second example, `&Proc.new {}` doesn't pass a block, it creates a new empty one.  One should omit `{}` and write it as `self.keep(&Proc.new)` or just `keep(&proc)` as `self.` is redundant and `proc` is the recommended synonym for `Proc.new`:

```rb
# passes on the block or the absence of a block
def discard(&block)
  self - keep(&block)
end

# passes on the block and fails if no block given
def discard
  self - keep(&proc)
end
```

Both `Proc.new` and `proc` without a block use the block of the current method.

`&proc` will fail if `discard` doesn't get a block.  So the first example is the best if you want to pass the block or the absence of a block (`&nil` passes no block at all).  The second example (as I changed it) is the best if missing block is an error.

In both cases, each time 'discard' is called, a new 'Proc' object is created, and it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

## March 2024 update:

You can also use [Anonymous Block Forwarding](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Naming/BlockForwarding), which is available since Ruby 3.1:

```ruby
def discard(&)
  keep(&)
end
```